# Apache 2.4 LogLevel and rewrite is ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to understand why my attempt at logging redirects and rewrites are failing in my config. I've added "LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6" to my virtual domain config and it isn't reflected in the error_log shown below.

I'm also having a problem with redirects. Can I log them in the same way to find out why they're seemingly being ignored?

I would like to redirect all requests for https://example.com/download.html to instead go to https://example.com/resource-center and only the third one below works. However, I want to be sure only /download.html off the root works, not /folder/download.html. How can I do this?

```
  Redirect 301 ^/download.html    /resource-center
  Redirect 301 ^download.html    /resource-center
  Redirect 301 /download.html    /resource-center
```

These redirects appear in the Include file with my config.

I've included the entirety of my config here, as I'm not sure which parts are needed to help troubleshoot this.

This is httpd-2.4.43-1.fc32.x86_64 on fedora32.

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
<VirtualHost 222.111.222.111:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com engage.example.com www.example.com support.example.com infocenter.example.com store.example.com updates.example.com
  ServerAdmin gdadmin@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example.com-443/html/
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/www.example.com-443/cgi-bin/
  ErrorLog /var/www/www.example.com-443/logs/error_log
  CustomLog /var/www/www.example.com-443/logs/access_log timing
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %T/%D %I/%O/%B H:%H U:%U gd443 s:%s V:%V v:%v" timing
  CustomLog "/var/www/www.example.com-443/logs/cached-requests.log" timing env=cache-hit
  CustomLog "/var/www/www.example.com-443/logs/uncached-requests.log" timing env=cache-miss
  CustomLog "/var/www/www.example.com-443/logs/revalidated-requests.log" timing env=cache-revalidate
  CustomLog "/var/www/www.example.com-443/logs/invalidated-requests.log" timing env=cache-invalidate
  LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6
  LogLevel error ssl:warn
  SuexecUserGroup guardian guardian
  HostnameLookups off
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^infocenter.example.com$
  RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/cloud-email-security? [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^store\.example\.com$
  RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/cloud-email-security? [L,R=301]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^list=
  RewriteRule /eng/                     https://example.com/?   [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule /advisories/              https://example.com/?   [R=301,L]
  KeepAliveTimeout 120
  Timeout 120
  ProxyTimeout 120
<IfModule mod_log_config.c>
  CustomLog "|/var/www/html/apache_pipelogger" "%v %p %m %B %D %s"
</IfModule>
  SecStatusEngine On
  <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
  
      <FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
          SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/example.sock|fcgi://localhost"
      </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <Directory "/var/www/www.example.com-443/html">
    AllowOverride all
    Options +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/example-old-links.htaccess
  </Directory>
  SSLEngine on
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
  Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
  Header always set X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"
  Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/fullchain.pem
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
   <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType text/css .css
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/plain text/xml application/javascript
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 222.111.222.111:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com engage.example.com www.example.com support.example.com infocenter.example.com store.example.com updates.example.com
  ServerAdmin gdadmin@example.com
  ErrorLog /var/www/www.example.com-443/logs/error_log
  CustomLog /var/www/www.example.com-443/logs/access_log timing
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %T/%D %I/%O/%B H:%H U:%U gd80 s:%s V:%V v:%v" timing
</VirtualHost>
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off
SSLSessionTickets       off
SSLUseStapling          on
SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
SSLStaplingCache        shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `LogLevel` directives in your config

```
LogLevel debug rewrite:trace6
LogLevel error ssl:warn
```

and the second one overrides the first one. Comment the second directive when debugging.

The redirect

```
Redirect 301 /download.html    /resource-center
```

looks fine to me, the other two won't work as expected since [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)
doesn't work with regexes as URL path (but [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) does).
It's also a feature of `mod_alias` and not of `mod_rewrite` if you're wondering why these requests are not logged with `rewrite:trace6`.

You could use a `RewriteRule` instead if you want to use `mod_rewrite`, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^/download\.html$ /resource-center [R=301,L]
```